# How can I subtract the value of the last date today from the value of the last date of the previous day in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I subtract the value of the last date today from the value of the last date of the previous day in mysql?

suppose today is 2022/05/27
then

**80 -20 = 60**

```
datetime,value

2022/05/27 15:25:30 ,20

2022/05/27 11:20:40 ,34

2022/05/26 9:42:10,80

2022/05/26 5:10:36,150
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using MySQL versions below 8.0,  which lack the latest features unfortunately. So I wrote  the code in 5.7 and tested it in workbench. To make things more interesting, I took the liberty of adding two rows on top of your original table.

```
insert test values('2022/05/25 15:10:36',200);
insert test values('2022/05/25 11:10:36',280);

select concat_ws(' minus ',t1.dt,t2.dt) as date_gap,
t1.`value`-t2.`value` as value_gap from
    (select date(`datetime`) dt,`value` from test where `datetime` in 
        (select max(`datetime`)mx from test group by date(`datetime`) ) 
    ) t1
 join
    (select date(`datetime`) dt,`value` from test where `datetime` in 
        (select max(`datetime`)mx from test group by date(`datetime`) ) 
    ) t2
on t1.dt = t2.dt - interval 1 day
;
```

Comment: Thanks it works. So i have another column named UniqueId (SKU) . How do i group by the result for each uniqueId ?

Comment: Your solution calcualate all date - (date-1) . My questino is just about today and yesterday. I have a huge amount of data.

Comment: Just add `order by t1.dt desc limit 1` at the end and you will get the intended result of  "2022-05-26 minus 2022-05-27 60" .